# Convert week number date YY-WW-DW into standard xslt date format YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: xslt, week-number, xslt-3.0

How can be converted week date YYWWWD, where YY - year, WW - week number and WD - week day 1-7 to a standard format YYYY-MM-DD for [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) using xslt 3.

Example: 21133
Year: 21
Week: 13
Week Day: 3 (Wednesday)
converted to 2021-03-31

Input:

```
<Line>
    <week>2113</week>
    <day>3</day>
</Line>
```

Output:

```
<Line>
    <Date>2021-03-31</Date>
</Line>
```

I tried calculation rules, but struggling with the logic for the dates around New Year like the case 20537 to be converted to 2021-01-03.

Comment: What are the rules for week numbering that your input provider uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example you could use as your starting point. It converts dates in [ISO week date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) format to standard YYYY-MM-DD date format:

**XML**

```
<input>
    <ISO-week-date>2006-W02-7</ISO-week-date>
    <ISO-week-date>2021-W13-3</ISO-week-date>
    <ISO-week-date>2020-W53-7</ISO-week-date>
</input>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/input">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="ISO-week-date">
            <!-- extract ISO-week-date components -->
            <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring(., 1, 4)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="week" select="xs:integer(substring(., 7, 2))"/>
            <xsl:variable name="weekday" select="xs:integer(substring(., 10, 1))"/>
            <!-- calculate base Sunday  -->
            <xsl:variable name="base" select="xs:date(concat($year, '-01-04'))"/>
            <xsl:variable name="base-weekday" select="xs:integer(format-date($base, '[F1]'))"/>
            <xsl:variable name="base-sunday" select="$base - $base-weekday * xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')"/>
            <!-- calculate standard date  -->
            <xsl:variable name="target-date" select="$base-sunday + ($week - 1) * xs:dayTimeDuration('P7D') + $weekday * xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')"/>
            <date>
                <xsl:value-of select="$target-date"/>
            </date>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<output>
   <date>2006-01-15</date>
   <date>2021-03-31</date>
   <date>2021-01-03</date>
</output>
```

If your week numbers follow the same convention as the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date and time standard, then you only need to adjust the parts that extract the input components.

Of course, if you need this in more than one place, you can turn this into a function.